# Is using a gnuplot variable in an external datafile manipulation command possible?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, gnuplot

Using an external datafile manipulation cmd in gnuplot looks like

```
plot '<(grep "1" "/path/datafile")' using 1:2 ...
```

Can we use a gnuplot variable in such a cmd like in

```
plot for [i=1:5] '<(grep "i" "/path/datafile")' using 1:2 ...
```

where `"i"` should be the gnuplot variable `i`.

Is it possible to hand over the gnuplot variable to the external command and how?
Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a string command using the concatenation operator ".". Eg

```
plot for [i=1:5] "<(grep '".i."' /path/datafile)" using 1:2 ...
```

You might want to grep for something less ambiguous than single digits like 1 that are likely to match within any number. For example, add word delimiters like `\b`, or even just a leading space. This is why I added the single quoting of the value as a preliminary step (we are generating `grep '1' ...`).

Comment: `grep -w` would look for the digit in isolation.